# R or postgres SQL code : How to identify all connected values in a table to identify unique networks

Tags: sql, r, recursion, social-networking, network-analysis

I have a problem which is a little close to that of a social network. I need to identify all the candidates in one network of friends and give that network of friends a network name or number. I would have to write this in SQL(postgres) or in R

"Createdcolumn(network)") is what i need to create at my end. Column1 and Column2 are already in my data

```
S.no/lineno        Column1      Column2    Createdcolumn(network)
   1                Peet         Jackson        1
   2                Jason        Filip          2
   3                Luke         Filip          2
   4                Jason        Becky          2
   5                Aron         Chris          3
   6                Maron        Cheese         4
   7                Matt         Brooklyn       5
   8                Brooklyn     Federer        5
   9                Ruselle      Federer        5
```

Little more info about the first figure to understand created column:

Lines  2,3,4 are together in network 2 because that is one circle of friends, here is the logic:

*lines 2 and 3 are connected because of Filip*

*lines 4 and 2 are connected because of Jason*

*(so now all lines 2,3 & 4 are actually one network since they are all connected in someway; maybe a friend of friend, or friend of friend of friend, or n times a friend of a friend)*

Likewise 7,8,9 are one network, here is the logic:

*lines 7 and 8 are one network because of Brooklyn*

*lines 8 and 9 are one network because of Federer*

*(so now all lines 7,8 & 9 are actually one network since they are connected in someway; maybe a friend of friend, or friend of friend of friend, or n times a friend of a friend)*

Line 1: Peet and Jackson has no other network of friends so that line is one network on its own

Line 5: Aron and Chris has no other network of friends so that line is one network on its own

Now

```
S.no/lineno        Column1      Column2    Createdcolumn(network)
   1                Peet         Jackson        1
   2                Jason        Filip          2
   3                Luke         Filip          2
   4                Jason        Becky          2
   5                Aron         Chris          3
   6                Maron        Cheese         4
   7                Matt         Brooklyn       5
   8                Brooklyn     Federer        5
   9                Ruselle      Federer        5
   10               Aron         Ruselle        5
```

now explaining fig 2 for better understanding:

in Fig2 I added "Aron" and "Ruselle" to line 10. So now  line 5 changed from network 3 to network 5 since all of them are connected:

*lines 7 and 8 are connected because of Brooklyn*

*lines 8 and 9 are connected because of Federer*

*lines 9 and 10 are connected network because of Ruselle*

*lines 5 and 10 are connected network because of Aron*

*(so now all lines 5,7,8,9 and 10 are actually one network since they are connected in someway)*

*Callouts:
1) the network 5 in the Fig2 can be renamed as network "3" too, no issues. Main idea to to have all 
 connected people as part of ONE network
2) My list is NOT dynamic and will NOT grow from list in Fig 1 to Fig 2, so i only need a solution which will get my work done in short term. Scaling solution is not required right now
3) My table has the same two columns but almost 40K unique names, so I CANNOT hardcode any names into my code
4) The names can be alphabetic, numeric of alphanumeric too*

I tried using complex full and cross joins but that was quite tedious. I read about the igraph package on R which might be what I am looking for

not sure if i explained my  question clearly. Apologies incase of any confusion*

Thanks

Comment: Dont apologise about not including pictures - they should not be used if possible. Just cut and past the actual data into your question to make it *much* easier to follow.

Comment: Much better - an interesting question. Think its doable in sql. What database are you using? It will probably be a recursive CTE if its available in your flavour.

Comment: its postgres SQL. I might be able to replicate this logic in R

Comment: I've updated my answer to postgres syntax. You should update your tags to include postgres as well.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT - Converted it to PostgresSQL syntax

Here is a solution, based on sql server cte syntax:

First create the table:

```
create table net(s int, c1 varchar(20), c2 varchar(20))
```

Next Populate with your data:

```
insert into net values 
(1,'Peet','Jackson')
,(2,'Jason','Filip')
,(3,'Luke','Filip')
,(4,'Jason','Becky')
,(5,'Aron','Chris')
,(6,'Maron','Cheese')
,(7,'Matt','Brooklyn')
,(8,'Brooklyn','Federer')
,(9,'Ruselle','Federer')
,(10,'Aron','Ruselle')
```

Now the CTE:

```
;with recursive cte as (
    select *, ','||c1||','||c2 as network, s as MaxS from net 
    union all
    select net.*, cte.network||','
    ||case when cte.network like '%'||net.c1||'%' then net.c2 else net.c1 end,net.s
    from net
    join cte on cte.network like '%'||','||net.c1||'%'  or cte.network like '%'||','||net.c2||'%'
    where net.s>cte.MaxS
) 
, groups as (
    select net.*, network, MaxS,
    row_number() over (partition by net.s order by length(network) desc) as longest
    from net
    join cte on cte.network like '%'||','||net.c1||'%'
) 
select s,c1,c2, 
dense_rank() over (order by MaxS) as groupno
from groups where longest=1
```

The result:

```
s   c1       c2     groupno
1   Peet     Jackson    1
2   Jason    Filip      2
3   Luke     Filip      2
4   Jason    Becky      2
6   Maron    Cheese     3
7   Matt     Brooklyn   4
8   Brooklyn Federer    4
9   Ruselle  Federer    4
10  Aron     Ruselle    4
5   Aron     Chris      4
```